# 1080p Screen resolution problem after 10.04 to 12.04 update

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, upgrade, resolution, samsung

I have a Samsung LCD 40" with a NVidia GeForce 6150SE nForce 430 Card.
I recently upgraded from 10.04 to 12.04 and the best resolution I can get is 1360x768.
I've tried the propietary drivers available on the repository

```
kmod:nvidia_current
kmod:nvidia_173_updates
kmod:nvidia_current_updates
kmod:nvidia_96
kmod:nvidia_96_updates
kmod:nvidia_173
```

I've also downloaded latest from NVidia's Web, version: `295.40.`
But still no luck.
With Nouveau driver, I can only get `1024x768`.

I know there is no problem with my hardware (video card, cable and monitor),  I was using it perfectly on `10.04`.

Can anybody suggest something else I could try, to get my `1920x1080` resolution back?

Here are some more information, that I got reading other similar posts on askubuntu.

`lspci | grep VGA`:

```
00:0d.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430] (rev a2)
```

`xrandr`:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 240, current 1360 x 768, maximum 1360 x 768
default connected 1360x768 0 0 0mm x 0mm
   1360x768       50.0     52.0* 
   1024x768       51.0  
   800x600        53.0     54.0     55.0  
   680x384        56.0     57.0  
   640x480        58.0  
   576x432        59.0  
   512x384        60.0  
   400x300        61.0     62.0     63.0  
   320x240        64.0
```

Comment: Just downloaded version 295.49 and still no luck. I can't get 1080p resolution.

Comment: Same results with 304.51, no 1080p available.

Answer (score 0):

I activated the Nvidia experimental drivers in Ubuntu 12.04 while in Unity 2D, then restarted and logged into Unity 3D and everything worked fine. Every time I tried activating it from Unity 3D it failed. I have a Nvidia 6150SE driver.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to add a new mode(resolution) by `xrandr` command:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_59.90"  106.29  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 901 904 932  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA 1920x1080_59.90
xrandr --output VGA --mode 1920x1080_59.90*
```